# Css for tags with any class or id

Tags: html, css

I used two image tags in one div tag. I tried to give different style with css to image tags, so that tags did not any class or id.
but I did not result.
Please correct my css

I used css like this :

```
div img { padding-right: 2px; vertical-align: middle; }
div img img { width: 16px; height: 16px; }

<div>
<img src="..." alt="" />
<img src="..." alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second line should be

```
div img + img { width: 16px; height: 16px; }
```

Child selector (+) is supported by all contemporary browsers while :last-child in IE is supported by IE9 and up only. IE6 is out of the scope no matter how you approach this.

Comment: In this case, all the images after the 2nd images will keep following this same rule. May be suit so well, if a different style is needed in the third case.

Comment: The task specifies exact situation @Starx: "I used two image tags in one div tag". The task does say 2.

Comment: I agree, just telling the limitation of the style. But anyways, a good fallback for IE. (Please dont say I offended you as well)

Comment: No, @Starx, I'm not offended in any way. Don't worry ;)

Answer (score 3):

Write your css like this

```
div img:first-child {}
div img:last-child {}
```

If you have more than 2 `<img>` inside the div use `:nth-child(N)`

---

As spliter mentioned, this is not supported by IE8, in this case use adjacent selector like he has showed in his answer.

Comment: Just a note, :last-child is not supported even by IE8.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do will possible without a class or id using the `:first-child` and `:last-child` selector.

```
div img img {}
```

The above identifies an `<img>` *inside* an `<img>` inside a `<div>`, which isn't what you have.

```
div img:first-child { padding-right: 2px; vertical-align: middle; }
div img:last-child { width: 16px; height: 16px; }
```

Comment: @Starx I was typing it as you were and finished typing it seconds after you did. In any case it's not identical. I add explanation as to why the OP's attempt failed.

Comment: @spliter, I am relaxed dude, didn't mean to offend @Michael. But ... seems like I did. So, I will remove my comments. No offence Michael, this also happens in SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 :nth-type-of selector, like bellow

```
div img:nth-of-type(1) {
    padding-right: 2px; vertical-align: middle;
}
div img:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 16px; height: 16px;
}
```

**However**, this will only work in browsers which support CSS3 (Chrome, Firefox, IE 9). To get backwards compatibility, you will need to either use Javascript (to loop over each element), or add a class to the images

Comment: Curious as to why someone downvoted this answer without providing any explanation? It works, and I provided information about browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
div img.img1 { padding-right: 2px; vertical-align: middle; }
div img.img2 { width: 16px; height: 16px; }


<div>
<img src="..." alt="" class="img1" />
<img src="..." alt="" class="img2" />
</div>
```